# How to extract all images from a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, extract, slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a PowerPoint presentation that is basically a slideshow.  How can I extract all the images into a folder?

I've seen articles that direct you to save the presentation as HTML, but this file format is not in the PowerPoint 2010.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the PowerPoint presentation in PowerPoint 2010.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on your keyboard.
3. Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications opens.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on your keyboard.
5. The Immediate window opens within Microsoft VBA.
6. Copy and paste the following text into the Immediate window:

   ```
   ActivePresentation.SaveAs "<Drive>:\users\<username>\desktop\<filename>.htm", ppSaveAsHTML, msoFalse
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
8. In PowerPoint, where your presentation once had the filename you had given it, it now says .htm (upon saving the presentation the title bar will revert back to its original name).

   Navigate to where your PowerPoint presentation is saved. There is now a folder with the same name as your presentation followed by _files. (Example: HTMLme_files)
9. Open the new folder.

   Included inside the folder are all of the audio and image files used in the presentation.

[Source of Information](http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2010/11/powerpoint-2007-2010-how-to-extract-audio-images-from-a-presentation-part-ii.html)

Comment: The problem is that it saves the entire slide as a PNG, not just the image.  I just want the image.

Comment: Check my edit above....

Comment: So does this mean Powerpoint 2010 doesn't let you export to HTML from the Save as... dialog? I just did that in Powerpoint 2003.

Answer (score 28):

Your presentation file likely has an extension like PPTX or PPSX.  Add .ZIP to the end of the file name (ie, give it a ZIP extension) then doubleclick it in Explorer.  This will open the file as though it were a ZIP file or zipped folder, which in fact it is.

Poke around within the folder structure and you'll find all of the original images that were inserted into the presentation originally.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a trick I use in PowerPoint 2010.

- Save the Powerpoint presentation as a XPS Document.
- Rename the saved document, replace the .xps extension with a .zip extension (as XPS documents are actually ZIP files containing a bunch of other files).
- Extract the ZIP file with your favorite ZIP extractor and check in the Resources\Images folder.

You should find in this folder the images that are stored in the PPT.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

If you have a version older than 2010 (unlike me) you can save as and choose html. Then all of your images show up in a folder.

If not, you and choose .png in Save As and this will turn each slide into a .png.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux/Ubuntu users in case it's a PPTX or PPSX (see [Steve Rindsbergs answer](https://superuser.com/a/294250/164726)) you can simply treat it as a ZIP file.

I openend it with file-roller: `file-roller presentation.pptx &`

Of course unzipping on command line works, too (`unzip presentation.pptx`).

In my case the images were in the `ppt/media` subdirectory.

Comment: I found that `file-roller` didn't open the file when the name had a `pptx` suffix. Renaming with a `zip` suffix seemed to make file-roller happy...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the online version of PowerPoint under Microsoft 365, so I can't vouch for PowerPoint 2010, but I hope it will help someone else with a more similar setup:

1. In PowerPoint, save the file as PDF
2. Use an online PDF tool with image extraction such as [PDFCandy](https://pdfcandy.com/extract-images.html) or [Smallpdf](https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-jpg) - make sure to choose to **extract images** rather than convert the slides/PDF to images. Caveats:

   - Please exercise caution when looking for such free online tools, as they'll either have usage limitations or may not have a good privacy policy for your files
   - It's possible that extraction might include items you don't want, such as backgrounds as shapes, so you will need to filter through the output

Answer (score 0):

In Office 2007 or 2010 install the addon  [SaveAsPDFandXPS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7) and save as pdf. Install [Pdf-Xchange viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (free). Open the pdf in this and under File -Export - Export image.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice can be used to convert the presentation to a zip file, which ends up having a Pictures directory in it with all the images.

I had a script to do this, but I can't find it now. I'll put it here if I do.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I deleted the script.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a small tool to help with this problem (it does this in-browser so you don't need to download and install anything dodgy). It will save you about 1 minute every time you need to do this :)

https://powerpointextractor.com/